# Sync Google Contact Groups with Apple iOS Contact Groups

Tags: mac, contacts, google

I am trying to sync my Google Contacts with my iPhone / Apple Contacts. The contacts sync fine, but the groups are not preserved. 
In Contacts for Mac, I can create a new group and add contacts to it, but that contact group will not sync across to Google Contacts, and vice versa.

Is there a way to keep these groups in sync?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do this yourself. The best way is to use a third party app. I've found "[Contacts Sync for Google Gmail](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/contacts-sync-for-google-gmail/id454390333?mt=8)" to be the best. There are iOS apps as well.

Best of luck!