# Q: How to configure Contacts.app with Google Contacts so that labels show up as contact groups?

Tags: data-synchronization, contacts, google, google-sync, contacts.app

I'm trying to get the Contacts app on MacOS Big Sur to display my Google contacts correctly. I have the account configured and the contacts themselves show up, but the Google contact tags (what Google calls "labels" and Apple calls "groups") aren't showing up.

Further, if I add a new contact group in the Contacts app under "Google" and use it to group several contacts, they seem to be stored locally (they are there after I reboot) but don't get pushed up to Google.

Any suggestions how to debug this further?

Comment: Perhaps contact Google?

Comment: Is what you want supposed to be supported?

Answer (score 0):

There's no straightforward way to do this yourself. Your options are to either give up on it or check out third-party tools.

See also: [Sync Google Contact Groups with Apple iOS Contact Groups](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/247668/sync-google-contact-groups-with-apple-ios-contact-groups)